# In Rails Migrations, what does the number specified for :limit on an integer represent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails Migrations, what does the number specified for the :limit parameter on an integer represent?  Is it the number of bytes or the number of digits?

i.e. If I were to specify the following:

```
t.integer :coefficient, :limit => 2
```

Does that mean the SQL database will reserve two bytes for each integer, or that each integer can not have more than two digits?  I'm assuming it means bytes, but I'm not positive.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, that should be

    t.integer :coefficient, :limit => 2

so that `:coefficient` is a symbol.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#M001735), it's the number of characters for `:string` and `:text` columns and the number of bytes for `:binary` and `:integer` columns.

Comment: The [documentation has moved](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column)